# How to stop downloading a youtube video in XCDYouTubeClient? [Swift]

Tags: ios, swift, video, download, youtube

I'm making a job to a company that requires the user to view videos from Youtube. So it has a player, and i'm using XCDYouTubeClient to download the videos, but if i tap on the cancel button, the iOS continues to downloading the video, consuming the user data plan unnecessarily.
Here's my code so far:

```
XCDYouTubeClient.defaultClient().getVideoWithIdentifier(videoId) { [weak playerViewController] (video: XCDYouTubeVideo?, error: NSError?) in
            if let streamURL = (video?.streamURLs[XCDYouTubeVideoQualityHTTPLiveStreaming] ??
                video?.streamURLs[XCDYouTubeVideoQuality.HD720.rawValue] ??
                video?.streamURLs[XCDYouTubeVideoQuality.Medium360.rawValue] ??
                video?.streamURLs[XCDYouTubeVideoQuality.Small240.rawValue]) {
                    //play the video
                    }
            } else {
                //dismiss the player
            }
        }
```

Then i have this function that is when the user press cancel:

```
func playerDoneButtonTouched() {
    //dismiss the player
}
```

I belive that in this function that i need to have a code to stop the downloading.

Thanks (: